# Bootstrap Jumbotron CSS Template is not working on Django Project

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, python-3.x

I am newer on Django projects and trying to apply Bootstrap to my Django website.

First of all, let me show you the screen that I get because it gives a better understanding in this way. This page is "about" ("hakkimizda" folder in my project structure) page of the website and it is a flatpage of Django.

[Page result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Nqm7.png)

My project structure is like this;

- my project
- - home
- - myproject
- - pages
- - static
- - - assets
- - - css
- - - dist
- - - images
- - - favicon.ico
- - templates
- - - flatpages
- - - - hakkimizda
- - - - - index.html
- - - - - jumbotron.css

In my index.html file, paths are like this;

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="/static/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
<link href="/static/assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="/templates/flatpages/hakkimizda/jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="/static/assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
```

Static folder contains Bootstrap's files. Pages folder is an application which is created for only flatpages.

Can you help me on this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ran `python manage.py collectstatic`?

[`collectstatic` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/staticfiles/)

Comment: this is development environment

Comment: Open your dev tools console on your browser and see what kind of error you're getting there. It'll help us to debug your problem more.

Also, it's usually better practice to use the `static` tag to serve your assets instead of hardcoding them like so: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'stylesheets/bootstrap.css' %}">`. Make sure that `STATIC_URL` is properly configured in your `settings.py`.